# How to call for Firefox bookmark dialog?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I've read this article on MDN:

 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Places_utilities_for_JavaScript#Bookmark_Dialog
But still has no clue how to call for function like

**showAddBookmarkUI()**

I tried `PlacesUtils.showAddBookmarkUI()`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article is [outdated as of Firefox 4](http://blog.bonardo.net/2010/04/28/about-the-recent-places-refactorings). This functionality is now implemented in the `PlacesUIUtils` module, method `showBookmarkDialog()`. You would call it like this:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var uri = Services.io.newURI("http://example.com/", null, null);

Components.utils.import("resource:///modules/PlacesUIUtils.jsm");
PlacesUIUtils.showBookmarkDialog({
  action: "add",
  type: "bookmark",
  uri: uri,
  title: "Example bookmark"
}, window);
```

This is an internal module so it isn't really documented and the API might change again in future. You can see an example of how it is being used [in the source code](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/814d0b2dbaba/browser/base/content/browser.js#l3200). Btw, if what you actually want to open is the list of bookmarks rather than the "Add Bookmark" dialog then you do it like this:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

var organizer = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow("Places:Organizer");
if (!organizer)
{
  // No currently open places window, so open one with the specified mode.
  openDialog("chrome://browser/content/places/places.xul", 
             "", "chrome,toolbar=yes,dialog=no,resizable", "AllBookmarks");
}
else
{
  organizer.PlacesOrganizer.selectLeftPaneQuery("AllBookmarks");
  organizer.focus();
}
```

(code mostly copied from [`PlacesCommandHook` implementation](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser-places.js)).

Comment: @R-U-Bn: This question isn't about the Add-on SDK, consequently the code doesn't use any of the SDK modules. I had to roll back your changes.

Comment: I see. I'm sorry. I guess I'll put it as another answer then, since the question itself doesn't say it shouldn't be SDK; right?  (Just for other people bumping here via google.)

Comment: You are free to do so of course, but I think the question clearly refers to classic addons.

Answer (score 0):

For SDK developers (google bump):

```js
const utils     = require('sdk/window/utils');
const window    = utils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow();

let { Cu } = require('chrome');
Cu.import("resource:///modules/PlacesUIUtils.jsm");

Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");    

//Adding bookmark    
var uri = Services.io.newURI("http://example.com/", null, null);
PlacesUIUtils.showBookmarkDialog({
    action: "add",
    type:   "bookmark",
    title:  "Predefined title",
    uri:    uri    
}, window);

//Editing existing one
PlacesUIUtils.showBookmarkDialog({ 
    action: "edit",
    type:   "bookmark",
    itemId: 575
}, window);
```