# Opening Bookmark Dialog from Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, post, bookmarks

The way I did it before with ***window.sidebar.addPanel()*** does not work for latest version of Firefox. I try to use ***PlacesUIUtils.showBookmarkDialog*** as adviced in [How to call for Firefox bookmark dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158187/how-to-call-for-firefox-bookmark-dialog)
It is (in the advice) preceded by ***Components.utils.import("resource:///modules/PlacesUIUtils.jsm");***

The problem is that documents tell that ***.import()*** may be called only on (local) file. I want the thing to work for a casual user (without requiring any plugins preinstalled).

Is this approach usable in general? Can I not import from elsewhere? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/985670 - the answer I got there is basically NOT IT IS NOT POSSIBLE to implement opening the Bookmarks Dialog in Firefox. So I have followed a simplified solution (though valid across browsers).

Comment: What simple solution?